# Utilizar o action do formulário corretamente

Tags: php, aplicação-web

estou tentando de forma simples, utilizar um formulário para inserir um comentário dentro de outra página, porém, não consigo chamar ele pra efetuar as devidas operações de insert na tabela que mostra os comentários. Ele insere normalmente no banco, mas o $id_topico fica zerado e aí a postagem não é inserida em tópico algum, só no banco mesmo.

**Mostrando um formulário simples com um campo de texto e o botão:**

```
                echo '<form method="post" action="reply.php">
                     <textarea name="reply-content"></textarea>
                    <!--Campo adicionando -->
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="$id_post" />
                    <input type="submit" value="Enviar"/>
                    </form>';
```

**Acessando o reply.php pra executar a operação com base no ID (aqui que não consigo pegar o id do tópico)**

```
    <?php
//reply.php
include 'index.php';
//include 'view_topico.php';

if(isset($_POST['id']))
{

$id_topico = $_POST['id'];

$sql = "SELECT
    topic_id,
    topic_subject
FROM
    topics
WHERE
    topic_id = '$id_topico'";


$result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);

}  

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST')
{
    //someone is calling the file directly, which we don't want
    echo 'Não é possível acessar diretamente a página de postagem.';
}
else
{
    //check for sign in status
    if(!$_SESSION['conectado'])
    {
        echo 'É necessário estar logado para fazer um comentário.';
    }
    else
    {

        //a real user posted a real reply
        $sql = "INSERT INTO 
                    posts(post_content,
                          post_date,
                          post_topic,
                          post_by) 
                VALUES ('" . $_POST['reply-content'] . "',
                        NOW(),
                        '$id_topico',
                        " . $_SESSION['idUser'] . ")";

        $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);

        if(!$result)
        {
            echo 'Não foi possível salvar seu comentário, tente novamente mais tarde.';
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'Comentário efetuado, volte para a <a href="view_topico.php?id=' . $id_topico. '">postagem</a>.';
        }
    }
}

?>
```

**O código inteiro de view_topico, que é onde está incluso o formulário:**

```
<?php
//exibir todas as categorias 
include('index.php');

if(isset($_GET['id']))
{

$id_post = $_GET['id'];

$sql = "SELECT
    topic_id,
    topic_subject
FROM
    topics
WHERE
    topic_id = '$id_post'";


$result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);

}   

if(!$result)
{
     echo 'O tópico não pode ser encontrado, tente novamente mais tarde.' . mysqli_error($db);
    }else{
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0)
    {
        echo 'Não encontramos nada, tente novamente.';
    }
    else
    {
        //mostrar os topicos
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))       
        {
            echo '<h2>Tópico: ′' . $row['topic_subject'] . '′ </h2>';
        }

        //query para os topicos
        $sql = "SELECT
                    posts.post_topic,
                    posts.post_content,
                    posts.post_date,
                    posts.post_by,
                    usuario.id,
                    usuario.usuario
                FROM
                     posts
                LEFT JOIN
                      usuario
                ON
                    posts.post_by = usuario.id
                WHERE
                posts.post_topic = '$id_post'";

        $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);

        if(!$result)
        {
            echo 'Não foi possível acessar a postagem, tente novamente mais tarde.';
        }
        else
        {
            if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0)
            {
                echo 'Não existe nenhuma postagem no tópico escolhido.';
            }
            else
            {
                //preparando a tabela
                echo '<table border="1">
                      <tr>
                        <th>Descrição</th>
                        <th>Data</th>
                        <th>Usuário</th>
                      </tr>'; 

                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
                {     
                    $user_post = $row['usuario'];          
                    echo '<tr>';
                        echo '<td class="input-group">';
                            echo '<h3><a' . $row['post_by'] . '">' . $row['post_content'] . '</a><h3>';
                        echo '</td>';
                        echo '<td class="input-group">';
                            echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime($row['post_date']));
                        echo '</td>';
                        echo '<td class="input-group">';
                            echo $user_post;
                        echo '</td>';
                        echo '<form method="post" action="reply.php">
                             <textarea name="reply-content"></textarea>
                            <!--Campo adicionando -->
                            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="$id_post" />
                            <input type="submit" value="Enviar"/>
                            </form>';
                    echo '</tr>';
                }
            }
    }
}
}

?>
```

Comment: Você poderia adicionar o arquivo ``reply.php``?

Comment: Oie, é esse 1° mesmo, percebi que marquei com //create_cat.php vou mudar o nome heeh testei o que você comentou, continua a inserir no banco mas agor com os seguintes erros: Notice: Undefined variable: id_topico in C:\xampp\htdocs\pin\reply.php on line 48

Notice: Undefined variable: id_topico in C:\xampp\htdocs\pin\reply.php on line 59

Comment: Use o var_dump para verificar a saída com a variável ``$id_topico``. Por exemplo: var_dump($_POST) e var_dump($id_topico);

Comment: Sim, executei pra ver e adivinha, tá retornando o próprio nome '$id_post' ao invés do id kkkk preciso tirar da forma de string, certo?

Comment: Desta forma:
 var_dump($_POST); var_dump($id_topico);

Comment: saída: array(2) { ["reply-content"]=> string(4) "gsdg" ["id"]=> string(8) "$id_post" }

Comment: Altere: de <input type="hidden" name="id" value="$id_post" /> **para** <input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.$id_post.'" />

Comment: Percebi. É importante ler bastante o manual do PHP e referências consolidadas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em primeiro lugar, o ideal, para inserção de dados, é usar o método **POST**.

> Por mais que esta também seja um opinião minha, segundo o W3Schools, programadores preferem POST a GET.
>   Dessa forma,
>   **tente:**

```php
echo '<form method="post" action="reply.php">
                             <textarea name="reply-content"></textarea>
<!--Campo adicionando -->
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="$id_post" />
                            <input type="submit" value="Enviar"/>
                            </form>';
```

//reply.php

> Muda de isset($_GET['id']) **para** isset($_POST['id'])

**e**

> $id_topico = $_GET['id']; **para** $id_topico = $_POST['id'];

Comment: Oks, fiz as substituições e continua sendo inserido o valor 0 na coluna de topic_id, como se não tivesse pego nada...... por que será?

Comment: Altera o código na sua pergunta com os dados alterados, por favor.

Comment: Esta parte deve ser alterada: echo '<form method="post" action="reply.php?id="'.$id_post.'">
                                 <textarea name="reply-content"></textarea>
                                <input type="submit" value="Enviar"/>
                                </form>';